# elementary OS Freya System Crashes

Tags: release-freya, system, power, battery

My computer is running elementary OS freya , but after working for some time my computer freezes. I can move the cursor all right but when I click on anything it does not respond. if i shut down my computer, it does not run, and charges % 2 remain. if you change battery, it computer run.

I have 245GB system and 250GB other partition and 2GB swap.

Comment: Are there any error messages? Try looking in dmesg.